# How authorise a Fetch call with Authorisation Token?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to call a [Freesound API](https://freesound.org/docs/api/index.html). Fetch throws an Unauthorised error whereas [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQEKg.jpg) works.

#### Code

```
const BASE_URL = "https://freesound.org/apiv2/sounds/";
const rain = "58835";
const APIKEY = "foo";

const headers = {
   method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Token ${APIKEY}`,
    },
   mode: "no-cors",
};

fetch(BASE_URL + rain, headers)
    .then((response) => response.json()) 
    .then((json) => console.log(json)) 
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: You posted your API key,. You'll need to get a new one now. Don't do this!

Comment: On Postman, do you get CORS headers in the response. Specifically, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? If so, you can set mode to `cors` and it should work.

Comment: I wrote [an article about no-cors](https://evertpot.com/no-cors/) after reading questions like these. I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should **never post API Key** on any public platform as anyone can access and exploit the API that you would have paid for.

#### Solution

The endpoint you're using seems to be invalid. Also, don't use `mode: 'no-cors'` unless an [opaque request](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types) serves your need. Else, you won't be able to access any property in the response object.

**Reason of 401 error:** Using `no-cors` prevents Authorization header to be added in your request.

**Getting past CORS error:** It usually happens in localhost during development. You can use an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) which would allow CORS.

```
const QUERY = 'piano';
const API_KEY = 'foo';
const BASE_URL = `https://freesound.org/apiv2/search/text/?query=${QUERY}`

const headers = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${API_KEY}`,
  }
};

fetch(BASE_URL, headers)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: no-cors will prevent setting an Authorization header too

Comment: Thanks for sharing that missing piece of information!

Comment: Thank you for answer but I'm getting ("Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://freesound.org/apiv2/sounds/58835. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).")  erorr without "no-cors".